# JasperReport set number of records per page

Tags: jasper-reports

after exporting jasperreport template, I found that the number of records per page depends on pageHeight.  Suppose I always want all the records to be on one page, is there a way to specify this?  is there a way to get how many records I want per page?  it seems to be depending on height of the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put in a page break that prints out when $V{REPORT_COUNT} == $P{SOME_NUMBER}.  This would force a new page to start.

You can't really ensure that all the records will be on one page unless you only get X number of records.  Jasper is built to output the data you give it and if you give it lots of data it will try to output it all.

You can do things like make the font smaller to put more data on the page or to use columns so that data will use the space more efficiently.

Maybe if you give a description of what you want to do a suggestion more suited to your needs may be possible? :)

Comment: theres a ignorePagination attribute for report that will put all records on one page.

Comment: is there any way set minimum for number of records per page??