# JasperReports: pdf form -- page break

Tags: forms, pdf, jasper-reports, ireport, page-break

I am trying to generate a PDF application (form) using *JasperReports* (*iReport*).

Here is the requirement :

I have a XML file that is the datasource for this report. I have an applicant and there can be number of dependants. I show dependant info in rectangular boxes (no jtable) one row per dependant. I need to add a page break after every dependant count 5.

Would pagebreak expression work here, in my view its easy to have pagebreak in case of standard report in tabular form, where you can restrict record count for every page. But what i am working on is not a report but a form with multiple formats.

Anybody has any idea as to how this can be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I limit the number of rows on each page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617082/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-on-each-page) & [JasperReport set number of records per page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045491/jasperreport-set-number-of-records-per-page) & [how to display data less than 5 row in jasper reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765774/how-to-display-data-less-than-5-row-in-jasper-reports)

Comment: Alex thanks for pointing me into right direction. I will give it a go using group expressions. It seems doable.

Comment: One more query, Can i have page number formatted for child pages. For e.g. Parent page number 1, child page number 1-1.

Comment: What do you mean `child page`?

Comment: I have this requirement, after page break, the new page sould have page number like 1-1, 2-2 etc. But this will happen only after page break. For e.g. 1(page break),1_1, 2(no page break),3(page break),3_1 ... so on.

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question.